# Automatic creation of a collection in the NFTs pallet

Tags: substrate-node-template, nft

I have a custom pallet that uses the NFTs pallet for the creation of NFTs. This pallet should have its own designated collection. It will only mint there.

Ideally I would like this collection to be created at initialisation of the system. How can I do this? I thought about using the on_initialize hook, but that's block and not system related, thus it doesn't feel right to me to use this hook for that purpose.

Comment: "initialisation of the system" do you mean in genesis?

Comment: In consider the genesis for sure a part of initialisation of the system, but does the creation of such a collection for a pallet belong at genesis? The genesis is also a one-time action, just as the creation of this pallet, so I do see an analogue here.

Thus if it's good practise to do this at genesis then that's fine for me. The question remains how I can do that though.

Comment: do you want the pallet itself to be the owner, i.e `PalletId::into_account()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a working solution of which the skeleton looks like the code below. This code is to be placed into the custom pallet.

```
#[pallet::genesis_config]
#[derive(frame_support::DefaultNoBound)]
pub struct GenesisConfig<T: Config> {
    // TODO: Required configuration fields here.
}

#[pallet::genesis_build]
impl<T: Config> BuildGenesisConfig for GenesisConfig<T> {
    fn build(&self) {
        // TODO: Initialisation code here.  
    }
}
```